# PHP array from jquery serialize, both work but which is correct?

Tags: php, arrays

I am using this to get a string from jquery to a php array via json.

```
    $navMenuLayout = array();
parse_str($layout['navMenu'], $navMenuLayout);
print_r($navMenuLayout);
```

But I noticed if I take out the first line then I still get the same output, does the first line matter?

```
parse_str($layout['navMenu'], $navMenuLayout);
print_r($navMenuLayout);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you don't have to predefine the variable for this function because PHP sets them automatically.

See the [example from PHP.net](https://www.php.net/parse_str) for what happens when the second argument is defined/undefined:

```
<?php
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
parse_str($str);
echo $first;  // value
echo $arr[0]; // foo bar
echo $arr[1]; // baz

parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz

?>
```

So, if you don't define the second argument, each key=>value pair in the string is made into an actual variable, whereas if you define a variable to be set, they are put into an array as that variable. PHP will automatically create everything for the function, you don't have to pre-define anything.

Answer (score 0):

`parse_str` is defined in the [php manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) as:

`void parse_str ( string $str [, array &$arr ] )`

The square brackets around the array argument mark it as optional. The `&` marks it as a reference argument, implying that an array will be created if a variable is passed in from the calling code.

So either is correct, but the first tells any maintainer of the code more about what you are expecting to send/get back from the function call without having to look it up in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

The `$navMenuLayout = array();` declares the variable. You can get away without declaring it first but if you have notices enabled in your php.ini error configuration, you'll get a notice informing you that an undeclared variable is being used (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting for setting your error logging levels).

`$navMenuLayout` is passed to the function with the intention replacing it's value with a result from the function.

If you look at http://www.php.net/parse_str , you'll see in the declaration that there is an & before the variable name: `parse_str ( string $str [, array &$arr ] )`. This means that the variable being passed will be over-written.

Comment: It will not produce a notice error as the function defines the variable automatically. In fact, notice errors are not even mentioned anywhere on the manual page, so I don't know where you got that from.

Comment: You're quite right. Looks like PHP actually does handle that automatically. I'm so used to seeing `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable:` when dealing with code-bases that I automatically assumed this would throw one too.